# TypeScript: Optimize nested forEach()

Tags: typescript, optimization

I have nested data with this interface:

```
interface CategoryList {
  name: string;
  level: number;
  id: number;
  parentId: number;
  categoryList?: CategoryList[];
}
```

So inside the categoryList have a CategoryList object but with different `level` from 3 to 6. I want to get the data each level and turn the data to be like the following interface:

```
interface NewCategoryList {
  name: string;
  level: number;
  id: number;
  parentId: number;
}
```

I have this so far and it worked perfectly but ugly:

```
function parseCategory(data: CategoryList, destination: NewCategoryList[]) {
  destination.push({
    id: data.id,
    name: data.name,
    level: data.level,
    parentId: data.parentId,
  });
}

function dataProcess(data: CategoryList[]) {
  //
  let data: NewCategoryList[] = [];
  //
  data.forEach((level_three) => {
    parseCategory(level_three, data);

    //
    if (level_three.categoryList) {
      level_three.categoryList.forEach((level_four) => {
        parseCategory(level_four, data);

        //
        if (level_four.categoryList) {
          level_four.categoryList.forEach((level_five) => {
            parseCategory(level_five, data);

            //
            if (level_five.categoryList) {
              level_five.categoryList.forEach((level_six) => {
                parseCategory(level_six, data);
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });

  writeFile(data, "data.json");
}
```

How to optimize this nested `forEach()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have this working so far:

```
function dataProcess(data: CategoryList[]): NewCategoryList[] {
  const destination: NewCategoryList[] = [];

  (function loop(value: CategoryList[]) {
    for (const element of value) {
      // push element to the output array
      destination.push({
        id: element.id,
        name: element.name,
        level: element.level,
        parentId: element.parentId,
      });
      // check if element has child category list
      if (element.categoryList) {
        // loop recursively to this function again
        loop(element.categoryList);
      }
    }
  })(data);
  return destination;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a recursive problem, start by making a function that you expect to call itself.

The code can be made cleaner by using lodash's `pick` and `flatten`

```js
interface CategoryListItem {
    name: string;
    level: number;
    id: number;
    categoryList?: CategoryListItem[];
}

interface NewCategoryListItem {
    name: string;
    level: number;
    id: number;
    parentId?: number;
}

const root: CategoryListItem = {
    id: 1,
    name: '1',
    level: 1,
    categoryList: [
        {
            id: 2,
            name: '2',
            level: 2,
            categoryList: [
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: '3',
                    level: 3,
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    name: '4',
                    level: 3,
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
};

function transform(item: CategoryListItem, parent?: NewCategoryListItem, level = 1): NewCategoryListItem[] {
    const newItem = {
        id: item.id,
        name: item.name,
        level,
        parentId: parent?.id,
    };

    const newChildren = item.categoryList?.map(child => transform(child, newItem, level + 1)) ?? [];
    const newChildrenFlat = ([] as NewCategoryListItem[]).concat(...newChildren);

    return [
        newItem,
        ...newChildrenFlat,
    ]
}

console.log(transform(root));

// 0: {id: 1, name: "1", level: 1, parentId: undefined}
// 1: {id: 2, name: "2", level: 2, parentId: 1}
// 2: {id: 3, name: "3", level: 3, parentId: 2}
// 3: { id: 4, name: "4", level: 3, parentId: 2 }
```